# Android - Intent or DialogFragment in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-dialogfragment

I dont know what path to take, I have a MainActivity class which host my ViewPagerTabStrip and each tabs are fragments, one tab consist of ListView and a button. When I click that button I want to either inflate a UI where the user fills in editfields or dialogFragment similiar process. Working with fragments what is best way to implement this? and How can I? I have set a onClickListener on the button and is working.

I have a method in my DBHelper that puts the users input into an SQLite database.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);
    add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onClick works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater= getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            //this is what I did to added the layout to the alert dialog
            View layout= inflarter.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog,null);
            alert.setView(layout);
            final EditText titleInput=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
            final EditText bodyInput=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_body);

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

What do I call in the Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to use an `AlertDialog` with a custom layout, which has has some `EditText`s. When the OK button in the dialog is clicked, get the values from the `EditText`s, and put them in your database.